# How can I know programmatically if a notification channel is enabled on Android O?

Tags: android

Looking at the docs I can see methods for checking all the attributes of a notification channel, but I couldn't find a way to check if the channel itself is enabled or disabled.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ReadChannel) has your answer:

> You can call the following two methods to discover the settings a user
>   has applied to a notification channel:
>
> - o retrieve a single notification channel, you can call `getNotificationChannel()`.
> - To retrieve all notification channels belonging to your app, you can call `getNotificationChannels()`.
>
> After you have the NotificationChannel, you can use methods such as
>   `getVibrationPattern()` and `getSound()` to find out what settings the
>   user currently has. To find out if a user blocked a notification
>   channel, you can call `getImportance()`. If the notification channel is
>   blocked, `getImportance()` returns **IMPORTANCE_NONE**.

So `getImportance()` will tell you if notification channel is blocked or not.

Comment: can you provide sample for `To retrieve all notification channels belonging to your app, you can call getNotificationChannels()` this I need help to get app channel sound uri

Answer (score 2):

Here is my full code:

```
public static boolean isNotificationChannelEnabled(@NonNull String groupId, @NonNull String... channelIds) {
    boolean appNotificationEnable = NotificationManagerCompat.from(AppContext.getContext()).areNotificationsEnabled();
    if (!appNotificationEnable) {
        return false;
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) AppContext.getContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            List<NotificationChannelGroup> groupList = manager.getNotificationChannelGroups();
            for (NotificationChannelGroup group : groupList) {
                if (TextUtils.equals(group.getId(), groupId)) {
                    if (group.isBlocked()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for (String channelId : channelIds) {
            NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);
            if (channel.getImportance() == NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For future Android versions beyond TIRAMISU**

```
fun Context.areNotificationsEnabled(): Boolean {
return when {
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU -> {
        // For future Android versions beyond TIRAMISU
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }
    Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O -> {
        // For Android Oreo (API level 26) and above
        
    }
    else -> {
       
    }
}
```

}